# Having issues with IBM Watson TTS using Curl

Tags: curl, websphere, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

Ive been using Curl and watson TTs for some time now.
All of a sudden it stopped working.
It created the audio file, but it is unplayable and has very small size

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:APIKEY" ^
--header "Content-Type: application/json" ^
--header "Accept: audio/wav" ^
--data "{\"text\":\"Test IBM Watson TTS.\"}" ^
--output Test.wav ^
"https://api.us-south.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/d73ba88c-84fc-45d2-b1bd-7b95066c280a/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_MichaelV3Voice"
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I just created a lite instance of Watson TTS and executed the same example request that you provided using curl with no problems (just swapped the "^" for "\"). Can you provide more details of your error?

Comment: I get no errors, It creates the audio file but is has Zero KB. I am using a Windows 10 pc

Comment: Are you using the Lite version of TTS? Have you tried generating new credentials or a new TTS instance? The url from your example appears to be ok, but make sure you are passing the apikey and url from TTS and not STT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your very small audio file will actually be a text file containing the error code. Either cat it or open it with a text editor and check what error it is reporting.

Comment: Your right! Error code is {"code":403, "error": "Forbidden"} I am going to try and generate a new api key first.

Comment: @GlennKline Please accept this answer, so that others can find it as an answered question, and not duplicate the question.