# IBM Watson Text to Speech Output File has No Sound

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I tried the IBM Watson Text to Speech curl example, it produced a .wav file. I also generated an .mp3, and .ogg files. none of them would play a sound output.  I am using Windows 10.

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{my apikey}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "text:hello world" --output hello_world.ogg "{my url}/v1/synthesize/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your audio files are not playing, then the chances are that they are not audio files. You are directing any output into your "audio" files, this includes any error messages. If you cat or browse an "audio" file, you will see that it contains text indicating why an audio file was not generated.

I guess this is a duplicate of [Having issues with IBM Watson TTS using Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802329/having-issues-with-ibm-watson-tts-using-curl/66886196#66886196)

> Answer update

Re: your comment - That error is typical of a json conversion error. Looking at the API documentation -  https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech#synthesize - the API is expecting the input data in a json format.

ie.

```
--data "{\"text\":\"Hello world\"}"
```

Comment: You are right sir.  This is what I found in the file:
{
   "error": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)",
   "code": 400,
   "code_description": "Bad Request"
}
What do you make of this?
I will check out the link you left in your reply.
Thank you.

Comment: You are right about the json syntax.  After doing some research on json I changed my code to this: curl -X POST -u "apikey:<redacted>" ^
--header "Accept: audio/wav" ^
--header "Content-Type: application/json" ^
--data @input.json ^
--output result.wav ^
"https://<redacted>/v1/synthesize" -v
The json file looks like this: {"text":"<p><s>This is the first sentence of the paragraph.</s><s>Here is another sentence.</s><s>Finally, this is the last sentence.</s></p>"} This works.  Thanks for all your help chughts.